# How to order the category that has most product

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not so clear in one of mysql.
i have two tables:

tblcategory
id, name

tblproduct
id, Name, Qty, Price, Category_id

and when i use sql to select all catogories to order by product count:

```
SELECT c.id,c.name,count(p.id) as product_count 
FROM tblcategory as c inner join tblproduct as p on c.id=p.category_id 
GROUP BY c.id,c.name 
ORDER BY product_count;
```

The result was that some category which has no product was not appear in my result! how can i get all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT c.id,c.name,count(p.id) as product_count 
FROM tblcategory as c left outer join tblproduct as p on c.id=p.category_id 
GROUP BY c.id,c.name 
ORDER BY product_count;
```

The `inner join` only keeps records that match in both tables.  You want all the product categories, even when there are no matches.  The `left outer join` keeps all records in the first table (`tblcategory`) along with any matching records in the second table (`tblproduct`).  If there are no products on a category, then you'll get a value of 0 instead of a missing row.